# Scrollable wrapper cuts out absolute elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow

I came across a problem of cutting off absolute child of relative child of a scrollable list.

My problem: https://youtu.be/uz5wmLEM04A 
Live prototype: https://jsfiddle.net/n0dowLhz/ 
My code (REACT): https://github.com/MoDrazzz/teamguru/blob/team-page/src/components/Teams/TeamMembers.tsx#L30-L34

The problem was also described [here](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/). With walkaround they have implemented, when menu is active, after scroll it stays in the same position.

The solution would be to make the menu visible no matter overflow is set to auto.

```
<!-- Has overflow: auto; --->
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some content</p>
     <!-- Must be relative --->
    <div>
      <button>Menu toggler</button>
      <!-- Absolute --->
      <div>Menu</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"With walkaround they have implemented, when menu is active, after scroll it stays in the same position."_ - can you please clarify what that means? I am having a hard time trying to figure out what the problem is supposed to be, based on your fiddle.

Comment: In linked article similar issue is presented. To fix it, authors positioned menu using javascript. The problem with that is when user scrolls the list, menu is in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the **popup element is being cut is because overflow is hidden**. The way to **fix** that is by **taking the popup element outside the container** (maybe somewhere in the body element) **and position it on the menu on click**.

**EDIT**

Important thing is to disabled any page/container scroll when the popup menu is shown and enable scroll when popup is hidden

Comment: You are right! But have you noticed that after I would scroll up / down, the menu would stay in the old position (the one set after click)?

Comment: The trick is that you have to disabled scrolling when you open the menu :)

Comment: Smart! I will give it a try :)

Comment: @MoDrazzz If my answer solved your problem, please vote and accept it so other users can easly solve similar issues.